# Javascript: regex for positive and negative number but no decimal point

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regex which only accepts positive and negative numbers. It should not include decimal point or any other characters except positive and negative numbers.

I have tried below regex but it accepts decimal point.

```
^-?\d*\.{0,1}\d+$
```

The regex should not allow any decimal point even it is before 0 e.g. **122334.0000**

Thank you.

Comment: Try: `/^[+-]?\d+$/`

Comment: What stops you [from dropping `\d*\.{0,1}`](https://regex101.com/r/An8F0S/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can try below regx.

```
^-?\d+$
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `\d{0,1}` in this regex?

Comment: You can remove this thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the below code.

```
^\-?[1-9]\d{0,2}$
```

OR

```
^[+-]?\d+$
```